# Sync adapter not auto syncing

Tags: synchronization, android-syncadapter

The update interval time given by me is 30s but the adapter doesn't sync in 30s and second strange behavior is that it syncs twice at start, i have registered all the xml and also registered the service in manifest still it wont sync in background

```
public class WeatherSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

private static final int WEATHER_NOTIFICATION_ID = 5004;
private static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = 30;
private static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL/3;

private static final String[] NOTIFY_WEATHER_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        weathertablecoloum.mWeatherIconId,
        weathertablecoloum.mMaxTemp,
        weathertablecoloum.mMinTemp,
        weathertablecoloum.mCondition
};

public final String LOG_TAG = WeatherSyncAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public WeatherSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Sync Started");
    try {
        boolean t = GetList.makelist(getContext());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyWeather();
}

public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
    AccountManager accountManager =  (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account newAccount = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));
    if ( null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount) ) {
        if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
            return null;
        }
        onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);
    }
    return newAccount;
}


public static void syncImmediately(Context context) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context), context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
}

public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
    Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
    String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                setSyncAdapter(account, authority).
                setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
    } else {
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }
}

private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
    WeatherSyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);
    //syncImmediately(context);
}

public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
  getSyncAccount(context);
}

private void notifyWeather() {
    Context context = getContext();
        Uri weatherUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(weathertable.mContentUri,"");
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(weatherUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int weatherId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(weathertablecoloum.mWeatherIconId));
            double high = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(weathertablecoloum.mMaxTemp));
            double low = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(weathertablecoloum.mMinTemp));
            String desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(weathertablecoloum.mCondition));
            int iconId = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            String contentText = String.format(context.getString(R.string.format_notification), desc,  String.valueOf(high),   String.valueOf(low));
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext()).setSmallIcon(iconId).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(contentText);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getContext());
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =  stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(WEATHER_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You won't probably get answers to your question if you keep tagging them with no android tag.

Comment: @Nikhil Soni i have the exactly same problem. Do you manage to resolve this issue?